Some of SOL being expended from wallet when I swap with Raydium how can i fix that?
I noticed that when I was trading meme coins on raydium, I was getting extra losses from time to time, so I opened Solscan to check.
It turns out that when I exchanged currency my sol was transferred as a deposit to an account that was created. When the transaction was completed, the deposit was not redeemed and the account was closed. Does anyone know what happened?


In your case, the sol are sent back to you, you can read it in the green circle you made. "and redeem to EBC..."

i saw that but I have no way of knowing the exact amount.

it is the deposited amount. On solscan you can also go to balance tab, and you will see differences pre/post transaction.

Your SOL is being used to create an account.
Rent is needed so that your account is alive and can be read/written to by validators.
Yes, it's possible to close the account and recover the SOL back if you are the authority, but for that, Raydium need to provide a mechanism to do this if their program owns the account.
fees on solana docs: https://solana.com/docs/core/fees

Thanks for the answer. So are the fees between deposit and redemption separate from the gas fee?
